# How far apart do tomato plantings need to be next year for crop rotation?

Tags: tomatoes, raised-beds, crop-rotation

Instead of cramming all my tomatoes in one bed, and rotating which bed is the tomato bed each year, I like to spread them around the garden. This means disease won't spread as easily if it does take hold and there isn't a concentrated target for pests.

How far away from last year's tomatoes should I plant next year's tomatoes for this to be effective? Is normal planting distance apart ok? For example could I do this?

[image]

then this the next year?

[image]

Comment: I can tell you what probably won't work. I have a smallish vegetable garden and rotate my beds, but my beds are only four feet deep, with 18 inch paths between them (so, about 1.3m deep with 0.5m paths on either side). When I rotate the plantings, the tomatoes move about 7 ft/2.3m. This apparently is NOT enough room to prevent the previous year's septoria from infecting the current crop of tomatoes. I do use cages and I used to sterilize them with bleach solution each spring, but saw no difference in septoria pressure, so I assume that the spacing isn't adequate.

Comment: Just move the soil. Crop rotation are good for medium and large fields, but for such size...roots, fertilizers (and diseases) can *travel*. No need to complicate things.